# ScreenMirroring in moto e

Tags: motorola-moto-e, smart-tv, miracast

I have moto e (XT1022) 1st gen phone, it runs on android 4.4.4 .

I have a smart TV Sony KDL-40W600B.

I am wondering whether my moto supports Miracast - screen mirroring or not. because it has option of the cast screen. But when I start screen mirroring in TV and go to cast screen option it doesn't show anything, even there is no option of finding the device.

EDIT
See the image, there is not option of searching a new device.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you should try for yourself if Miracast works because I don't have that phone.

Comment: Well it does not work, but there is a option in setting for casting screen, that's why I am asking the question here.

Comment: When you are in the `cast screen` option, press your `menu button` and tap `wirelles display`

Comment: See the edited question.

Comment: long press the recents button. Do you see an option now?

Comment: Nothing - no options :(

Comment: Then I think your device is not supported.